# Question about question: can I ask and answer this?

Tags: discussion, lists

I have plenty of illustrations make in TikZ related to math and physics done in the last several years. Currently I'm working on the small catalogization and update of this things.

Can I make a list on TeX.SE with a small description and a detail question and answer of this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you would post a proper question which is answerable, let people time to post their own answers, why not. Just remember that it's a question and answer site, not a gallery.

If you would like, you can contribute your examples to the [TikZ Example Gallery](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/). There your examples would be tagged by features, topic, field of science, and author. I maintain this site, you can find my email address on the [contact page](http://texample.net/contact/).